# How to handle child objects that need DB interaction for their business logic

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I've started reading [Domain Driven Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design).

I've got a situation where an Aggregate Root has a child object that needs DB interaction in order to perform it's business logic because one of the constants it uses is saved in the DB.

#### Example:

- User creates a `Customer`
- User creates a `Review` on that `Customer`
- `Review` might need approval if the `Customer`'s age is below a `cutoffAge`
- The `cutoffAge` constant used in the `Review` business logic is saved in the DB

```js
class Customer {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.review = null;
  }

  createReview() {
    this.review = new Review(this.age);
  }
}


class Review {
  constructor(age) {
    // Where `approvalAgeCutoff` value should really come from the DB
    this.approvalAgeCutoff = 10;
    this.needsApproval = false;

    if (age < this.approvalAgeCutoff) {
      this.needsApproval = true;
    }
  }
}


// Usage

const customer = new Customer('John Doe', 15); 
customer.createReview();
```

What's a recommended way of handling this without adding DB interaction code in the `Review` child object?

Answer (score 4):

I would pass all the required information down as a method parameter in order to keep the Aggregate as clean as possible.

```
class Customer {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.review = null;
  }

  createReview(approvalAgeCutoff) {
    this.review = new Review(this.age, approvalAgeCutoff);
  }
}


class Review {
  constructor(age, approvalAgeCutoff) {
    this.needsApproval = false;

    if (age < approvalAgeCutoff) {
      this.needsApproval = true;
    }
  }
}


// Usage, in an Application service

const approvalAgeCutoff = someDb.loadApprovalAgeCutoff();
const customer = new Customer('John Doe', 15); 
customer.createReview(approvalAgeCutoff);
```

Then, when using it, the client code (most probable an `Application service`) would load that value from the DB and pass it to `customer.createReview`.

In this way you keep the Aggregate clean and testable without using a mock.

Answer (score 3):

> What's a recommended way of handling this without adding DB interaction code in the Review child object?

That sounds to me like a `ReviewPolicy`, or some such, with state that lives outside the Customer aggregate.

As such, the usual way of querying the policy within a command that updates the user would be to use a *domain service*.  Most commonly, you would pass the domain service to the aggregate as an argument in the command; and the entities within the aggregate would invoke the query when they need it.